# GIT show all commits from branch missing in master using git cherry and format

Tags: git, command-line-interface, branching-and-merging, xargs, git-cherry

I want to use `git cherry` to show all commits that went to a specific branch but are missing from the master branch and log this using pretty format.

I tried this:

```
git cherry master branch_name | grep "^+" | sed 's/^+ //' | xargs -I {} git --no-pager log --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%d,%ae,%ad,%s' --date=short -1 {}
```

What this does is to:

1. `git cherry master branch_name` - list in the terminal line by line all hashes of commits that have code in branch_name and not in master and the other way around with a + or a - sign before the hash.
2. `grep "^+"` - get only those that start with a + (the ones missing in master from branch_name actually)
3. `sed 's/^+ //'` - remove the `+` from the line so we can get only the hash.
4. `xargs -I {} git --no-pager log --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%d,%ae,%ad,%s' --date=short -1 {}` - passes each hash as a parameter to git log to show the formatted log of each hash. Here `--no-pager` mean to exit git log window and `-1` to show only 1 commit.

The problem with this is that it starts concatenating each result for each hash returned from git cherry on the same line. It doesn't execute it line by line so I can copy paste them or so I can save them to a csv file using `... > tmp.csv`.

Not sure if there is anything else I can use apart for `xargs` or if that is actually a problem with git log and this won't work.

What am I missing? and what am I doing wrong?

Thank you all and sorry for being a noob.

Comment: Can you just add a `| tr ' ' '\n' ` into your pipeline before the xargs to replace spaces with newlines? (Or replace with nulls, and use `xargs -0`.)

Comment: Add `%n` in the end of the format string for a newline.

Comment: @Mort How wil `tr` help here, there are no spaces, `sed` takes care of that.

Comment: @ElpieKay True, that is a way to fix this, but I was actually looking to an explanation to why this is happening and what will be a better way of doing this. Thanks anyway for the quick fix to my current setup.

Comment: @RaduM it seems it's caused by `--no-pager`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I don't get it why, even if I pipe `| less -F -X` at the end and remove the no-pager thing, is still the same issue, all logged in one line.

Comment: @RaduM How about just removing `--no-pager` from your command? I don't think it's needed here.

Comment: @ElpieKay If I do that I will have to press Q on every line that gets returned. I need all logged on the console in one go. I don't think you understand what that pager is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121272/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-radum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `--pretty=format:...`.  Note that [there is a `--pretty=tformat:...` as well](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), and that *it is a default*:

> **Commit Formatting**
>
> `--pretty[=<format>], --format=<format>`
>
> Pretty-print the contents of the commit logs in a given format ... When <format> is [not a predefined format like short, medium, oneline, etc] and has %placeholder in it, it acts as if `--pretty=tformat:<format>` were given.
>
> ...
>
> The `tformat:` format works exactly like `format:`, except that it provides "terminator" semantics instead of "separator" semantics.  In other words, each commit has the message terminator character (usually a newline) appended, rather than a separator placed between entries. This means that the final entry of a single-line format will be properly terminated with a new line ...

The `--pretty=tformat:...` form can therefore be abbreviated as `--format=...`.

#### Simplifying: `--no-walk` and `sed` tricks

Aside from this, there's a somewhat better (more efficient) way to achieve the desired result.  You can still use `git cherry` like this, and use `sed` to strip off the markers, just as before.  You can omit the `grep` since `sed` can do that as well: use `sed -n` and `s/pattern/replacement/p`.  And, now that you have selected the right commits, you can then give them all as arguments to one `git log` command, and use `--no-walk` to make `git log` look *only* at the supplied hashes, and not at any of their ancestors.

That is, instead of:

```
git cherry master branch_name | grep "^+" | sed 's/^+ //' | xargs -I {} \
    git --no-pager log --format='%h,%an,%d,%ae,%ad,%s' --date=short -1 {}
```

you could do:

```
git log --no-walk --format='%h,%an,%d,%ae,%ad,%s' --date=short \
    $(git cherry master branch_name | sed -n 's/^+ //p')
```

(you can now omit `--no-pager` too, as I did, since it's safe enough to let the pager run).

#### But in fact, it's all built in

If `git log` were not essentially the same command as `git rev-list`, this would be the way to go—but in fact, `git log` and `git rev-list` take all the same commit selection arguments.  Furthermore, `git cherry` is mostly just a front end for `git rev-list`,<sup>1</sup> so there's an even more efficient way to do this:

```
git log --right-only --cherry-pick --format="$format" master...branch
```

where `$format` is your desired format.  (I *think*—getting the left/right only, cherry-pick/cherry-mark arguments correct is a bit tricky; this is based on a quick scan through the man page and somewhat hasty reading of your question.)

---

<sup>1</sup> When using `git cherry` with a `<limit>` argument, I am not sure you can get the same from `git rev-list`, though `^<limit>` might work.